# Classifying empirical and non-empirical research in the social sciences

Tags: methodology, social-science

I am looking for a definition or a classification system (or a reference to an existing system) that can be used to reliably classify a very large set of articles into empirical vs. non-empirical research.  The articles are all from the social sciences and represent the full range of study and article types, including qualitative and quantitative research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about academia, but about automated text classification.

Comment: @gerrit:  Indeed, it is involving text classification, but the question itself is on the definition of empirical versus non-empirical research produced by academics, similar to this question:  http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/what-is-an-empirical-study

Comment: Then perhaps I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @gerrit: You are correct that automated text classification is not on-topic here, but the subject and manner of the classification of this specific question are, as they are inherently about academia. Thus I consider this on-topic.